# DateTime for start Event Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I try to get a start date and time for the user to schedule a meeting.
When I click my ed_start_date a DatePicker and a TimePicker show up one by one.
My question is: How can I do this more simply than that and how can I store the value selected to inserted into SQLite database... tks for advice

Something that will fit righ is google calendar input for set starDateTime and stopDateTime

```
if (v == ed_start_date) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        startYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        startMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        startDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        startHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        startMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

         DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if(year>=startYear & monthOfYear>=startMonth &         dayOfMonth>=startDay)
                        ed_start_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                        else
                        Toast.makeText(MeetingsAddEditActivity.this, "Selected date can not be less than current date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                        if(hourOfDay>startHour)
                            ed_start_date.append(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MeetingsAddEditActivity.this, "Selected time can not be less than current time!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, startHour, startMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();

      }


    if (v == ed_stop_date) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        stopYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        stopMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        stopDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        stopHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        stopMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        if(year==startYear & monthOfYear==startMonth & dayOfMonth==startDay)
                            ed_stop_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MeetingsAddEditActivity.this, "Selected date can not be different than start date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, stopYear, stopMonth, stopDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();


        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                        if(hourOfDay>=startHour)
                            ed_stop_date.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MeetingsAddEditActivity.this, "Selected time can not be less than start time!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, stopHour, stopMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this would be to create a custom dialog that includes both a timepicker and a datepicker.  That way the user can set the date and time in the same dialog before dismissing.

Easiest way may be to use a library such as https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

or create a custom layout and inflate it.